# Regular expression - Text between colons

Tags: regex

I have a schema like this

```
<h1>
5/2009
<br/>
Question: This is the question
</h1>
```

I like to get the first part after the `<br/>` or always the string before the colon `:`

--> Solution should be "Question"

Attention: This words change - Sometimes its question, othertime may be big question ....

I tried with `<h1>(.{0,50}):(.{0,50})` but this returns to much (also the date)

I'm not trained with regex, can anyone help me with this?

Thank you alot.

Comment: If someone has given you help to the extent of being your hero, it is customary to select their answer - click on the tick-mark under the answer, and it will bestow 15 points on the answerer, and 2 points and a badge on yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<br/>([^:]+):
```

Comment: Yes.  First, extract the contents of the `<h1>` element with an HTML parser, then apply this regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work:

```
<h1>.*?<br />([^:]+):(.*?)</h1>
```

Comment: May be I'm wrong, but what is the need of `?` in `<h1>.*?` Doesn't `.*` mean zero or more occurrences of any character?

Comment: Yes, but it will also match `<br />` which becomes a problem if there is more than one `<br />` inside the h1 tag, or if there is more than one h1 tag inside the string you're applying the regex to. The ? makes the preceding quantifier lazy, ensuring that the rest matches at the earliest possible location.

Comment: ? means non-greedy (i.e. match as little as possible - default is match as much as possible). If not used and the page contains two <h1> tags it will get the <h1> from the first and the </h1> from the last.

Comment: Thanks all. Greediness is a tricky thing. Googling gave me this http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html Everyday I'm learning something about regex just by hanging out here in SO !!!

Comment: but how can i acces to the first part? with asp.net and c#?

i try

        string RegexGeschaeftstyp = @"<h1>.*?<br>([^:]+):(.*?)</h1>";
        MatchCollection RegexGeschaeftstypMatches = Regex.Matches(strSource, RegexGeschaeftstyp);
        foreach (Match match1 in RegexGeschaeftstypMatches)
        {
            Response.Write("Found " + match1.ToString() + " at position " + match1.Index + ".<br>");
        }

Comment: Did a quick Google, something like that should be right. Maybe match1.Value instead of match1.ToString()... not really sure, I've never used Regex in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you mean and translate that into the regex language.  As Gumbo has pointed out, you should be using `[^:]` instead of `.`; the reason for this is that you are looking for groups of characters that aren't colons (`[^:]`), not for groups of absolutely any character at all[1] (`.`) which happen to have colons between them.

Any time you find yourself using `.` with a quantifier in a regex, stop and ask yourself whether you really mean "any character" or whether you could express your meaning more clearly (and get more accurate results) using a character class instead.

(Non-greedy quantifiers (`.*?`) can also do the job of getting correct matches in cases like this, but character classes are still a clearer expression of intent for human readers and improve efficiency by avoiding excessive backtracking for machine readers.)

[1] Well, absolutely any character at all, with the possible exception of newlines depending on the regex implementation that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

my brain's floooding. really thanks to all who already helped.

may be anyone can try to help again is so important for me :S?

```
<ul>
<li>
07.05.2009:
<a href="#1">Test 1</a>
</li>
<li>
05.01.2009:
<a href="#2">Test 2</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

This Time I like to read the second part. The best thing would be, if I get both seperate in one regex..

So: 1. 07.05.2009
    2. Test 1

Comment: This auxilliary question is now a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564665/regular-expression-exclude-not-needed

Comment: Please don't post questions as an answer.