# Regular expression - exclude not needed

Tags: regex

My brain's flooding. Really thanks to all who already helped yesterday.
(If I add anything to the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559228/regular-expression-text-between-colons) of yesterday, it's not shown by the newest questions?)

Maybe someone can try to help again; it's so important for me :S

```
<ul>
<li>
07.05.2009:
<a href="#1">Test 1</a>
</li>
<li>
05.01.2009:
<a href="#2">Test 2</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

This time I need to read the second part. The best thing would be if I get both separately in one regex.

So:

1. 07.05.2009
2. Test 1

I try with this

```
<li>.*?</li>(.*)</a></li>
```

but I need to exclude also all before Test 1 and Test 2

Comment: You should include a cross-reference to yesterday's question.

Comment: Why not use a HTML parser library like lxml or ElementTree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I second Johannes Rössel, but I would cut away the line breaks in front of the date part with

```
<li>[\s]*([^:<]*)[^<]*<a[^>]*>([^<]*)
```

Comment: I write them by heart and check them with a tool like Expresso with multiple inputs

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
<li>([^:<]*)[^<]*<a[^>]*>([^<]*)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<li>([^>]*)<a[^>]*>([^>]*)</a></li>
```